# Adobe Premiere cursor problem

Tags: premiere, premiere-pro

When I try to drag and drop an effect to adjustment layer, the cursor become frozen and can't be used to attach any effect to a layer.

What are the solutions for this? Any solutions will be accepted.

Comment: This would be better addressed to Adobe as it is likely to require a specific computer set-up to reproduce.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, or an underspec computer running out of memory.